# powershell added 3 elements to a list

Tags: powershell

In a function I added 3 object to a list. But the function returns 6 objects.
Where does it go wrong? $data has 3 elements but $tgrp 6.

```
function GenerateGroups ($dept)
{
    $data = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
    $grG = -join ("BE_", $dept)
    $RO = -join ("BE_FS_", $dept, "_RO")
    $RW = -join ("BE_FS_", $dept, "_RW")
    $FC= -join ("BE_FS_", $dept, "_FC")
    $GP = AddGobalGroup -group $grG -name $grG
    $GPO = AddDomainGroup -group $RO -name $RO
    $GPW = AddDomainGroup -group $RW -name $RW -member $GP
    $GPF = AddDomainGroup -group $FC  -name $FC

    $data.Add($GPO)
    $data.Add($GPF)
    $data.Add($GPW)
    Return $data
}



$dept = "ER8skk4xxk871"

[System.Collections.ArrayList]$tgrp=GenerateGroups -dept $dept
```

Solved.

```
    $data += $GPO
    $data += $GPF
    $data += $GPW
    
    Return $data
}
```

Comment: From the [`Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.add?view=net-6.0#system-collections-arraylist-add(system-object)) method: ___Returns Int32: "The ArrayList index at which the value has been added."___ you're capturing that output, `$null = $data.Add(...)` should solve that problem.

Comment: To complement Santiago's comment: Any output - be it from a PowerShell command, an operator-based expression, or a .NET method call - that is neither captured in a variable nor redirected (sent through the pipeline or to a file) is _implicitly output_ from a script or function. To simply _discard_ such output, use `$null = ...`.
If you don't discard such output, it becomes part of a script or function's "return value" (stream of output objects). The linked duplicate has details.